# Python Inheritance: Why does the Folder class inherit from the File class

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance

The below code is from a book I'm reading related to OOP in Python 3.  Can someone help me understand the logic of the below?  It seems counterintuitive that the Folder class inherits from the File class.  For example, in the below, when a Folder is instantiated, it seems that a File is also instantiated with the same name but in reality you would not want this to happen.  What am I missing?

```
class File:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Folder(File):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.children = []

root = Folder("")
etc = Folder("etc")
root.children.append(etc)
etc.children.append(File("passwd"))
etc.children.append(File("groups"))
httpd = Folder("httpd")
etc.children.append(httpd)
httpd.children.append(File("http.conf"))
var = Folder("var")
root.children.append(var)
log = Folder("log")
var.children.append(log)
log.children.append(File("messages"))
log.children.append(File("kernel"))
```

Comment: The main effect of Folder inheriting from File is that it has access to File's methods, which can be seen in the init call. The super() means it runs File's init, which sets the name attribute. So an instance of Folder will have a name and children whereas an instance of File will only have a name. When you create an instance of Folder, it will not also create an instance of File, it will only call File's init which will assign the name attribute for the Folder instance

Comment: To be fair it's a bad example for teaching inheritance. This is actually how some filesystems are implemented (like most Unix filesystems where everything, including directories, is a file, and when you create a folder you actually create a file) but unless you happen to know that, it is a bit counterintuitive indeed.